# How can I break or get around the encryption on my WD My Book Essential (Smartware)?

Tags: hard-drive, encryption

I have a WD Western Digital My Book Essential 1TB Hard Drive which comes with WD Smartware software. I had put a password in it without a hint and now I have lost the password. This hard drive use 256 bit hardware encryption. All my personnel and important data is in it and I am unable to remember the password.

How can I unlock the drive without formatting it, is there any way to crack or hack the smartware and unlock it?

How can I get my data?

Answer (score 3):

I feel sorry for you, but this so called "smart" ware leaves you no choice but to either **remember the password** or **format the disk.** Its really a shame that WD did not think of some kind of service to unlock such legitimate lock-out scenarios.

[This page](http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3741#failed) details your only options (That are the two I mentioned above).

Answer (score 2):

The [manual](http://www.wdc.com/wdproducts/library/UM/ENG/4779-705053.pdf) says

> CAUTION!  The WD SmartWare software uses your password to electronically 
>   lock and unlock your drive. **If you forget your password, you will not be able to 
>   access the data that is on your drive** or write new data to it. You will have to erase 
>   the drive before you can use it again.

There are no details about the encryption algorith though it does talk about 256-bit hardware-based encryption. This suggests there is no practical way to recover the data other than to keep trying passwords.

I would write down all the passwords or pass-phrases I could think of, write down all likely variations of each one (e.g. might you have used upper-case on some letters, might you have replaced some letters with similar digits, might you have added punctuation?)

I would then go through them all systematically and tick off the variations of all passwords one by one.